# Is there a packing function?

Tags: math, cryptography

I am interested in whether there is a function f(x, k) such that:

```
f(x1, k1) = k2
f(x2, k2) = k3
f(x3, k3) = k4
...
f(xn, kn) = kn+1
```

and was reversible, that is, I could know k4 to know k3 and x3?

I have a feeling that such a function does not exist, as it would solve a lot of practical problems, maybe there is some evidence of the impossibility of such a function?

P.S perhaps there are such functions, but they do not scale because of collisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard trick to achieve something like this is to use multiplication of prime numbers.

Without loss of generality, let ***x<sub>n</sub>*** and ***k<sub>n</sub>*** be arbitrary positive natural numbers. (We are going to restrict ourselves to positive natural numbers which can be trivially extended to any countable set, e.g. integers, rationals, floats, strings, enums, booleans, etc. but not, for example, reals. In other words: anything Turing-computable should work.)

Let ***p(n)*** be the ***n***<sup>th</sup> *odd prime number* (the odd prime numbers are essentially the primes without 2, or the series of primes shifted by 1). E.g., ***p(3) = 7***.

Let ***f(x<sub>n</sub>, k<sub>n</sub>) = p(x<sub>n</sub>) × p(k<sub>n</sub>)***.

Then, ***x<sub>n−1</sub>*** and ***k<sub>n−1</sub>*** can be reconstructed from ***k<sub>n</sub>*** by prime factorization of ***k<sub>n</sub>***. Actually, there is a little hiccup: the prime factorization will give us the two prime factors, but we don't know which prime factor is ***x<sub>n</sub>*** and which is ***k<sub>n</sub>***.

We can fix this, though, by defining that:

- By default, the smaller number is ***x<sub>n</sub>*** and the bigger number is ***k<sub>n</sub>***
- If that is *not* true, we add 1 to the result.

So, the full definition is:

Let ***f(x<sub>n</sub>, k<sub>n</sub>) = p(x<sub>n</sub>) × p(k<sub>n</sub>) if x<sub>n</sub> ≤ k<sub>n</sub>, p(x<sub>n</sub>) × p(k<sub>n</sub>) + 1 otherwise***.

Example for ***x<sub>1</sub> = 4***, ***x<sub>2</sub> = 8***, ***x<sub>3</sub> = 15***, ***x<sub>4</sub> = 16***, ***x<sub>5</sub> = 23***, and ***k<sub>1</sub> = 42***:

1. ***f(4, 42) = 11 × 191 = 2101***
2. ***f(8, 2101) = 23 × 18341 = 421843***
3. ***f(15, 421843) = 53 × 6140473 = 325445069***
4. ***f(16, 325445069) = 59 × 7037198743 = 415194725837***
5. ***f(23, 415194725837) = 89 × ~12076000000000 = ???***

As you can see, this gets a bit unwieldy: I couldn't easily find a prime number table that includes the 415194725837<sup>th</sup> prime. However, that is not a problem: there is no requirement that ***f*** and ***f<sup>−1</sup>*** be efficiently computable, only that they exist. And since we know there are infinitely many primes, we know we can always find ***p(x<sub>n</sub>)*** and ***p(k<sub>n</sub>)***.

Here is a different encoding that can be trivially calculated by hand:

Let ***f(x<sub>n</sub>, k<sub>n</sub>)*** be the intercalation of the digits of the representations of ***x<sub>n</sub>*** and ***k<sub>n</sub>*** in an arbitrary base greater than 1. (It doesn't really matter what base you choose for the representation as long as you are consistent. In other words, it doesn't have to be literal *digits*, i.e. decimal, it could just as well be binary, ternary, octal, hexadecimal, sexagesimal, base-64, base-85, or base-123456789.) In order to deal with leading zeroes, we prepend a single ***1***.

Then, ***x<sub>n−1</sub>*** and ***k<sub>n−1</sub>*** can be reconstructed from ***k<sub>n</sub>*** by stripping off the ***1*** and extracting alternating digits.

Example in base-10 for ***x<sub>1</sub> = 4***, ***x<sub>2</sub> = 8***, ***x<sub>3</sub> = 15***, ***x<sub>4</sub> = 16***, ***x<sub>5</sub> = 23***, and ***k<sub>1</sub> = 42***:

1. ***f(4, 42) = 10442***
2. ***f(8, 10442) = 10100040482***
3. ***f(15, 10100040482) = 10100010000000400041852***
4. ***f(16, 10100010000000400041852) = 10100010000000100000000000000040000000401081562***
5. ***f(23, 10100010000000100000000000000040000000401081562) = 10100010000000100000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000040001000801052632***

And in order to reverse it:

1. ***f<sup>−1</sup>(10100010000000100000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000040001000801052632)***
2. Strip off the leading ***1***: ***0100010000000100000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000040001000801052632***
3. Take each alternating digit:

   - ***x<sub>5</sub> = 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000023***
   - ***k<sub>5</sub> = 10100010000000100000000000000040000000401081562***
4. ***f<sup>−1</sup>(10100010000000100000000000000040000000401081562)***
5. Strip off the leading ***1***: ***0100010000000100000000000000040000000401081562***
6. Take each alternating digit:

   - ***x<sub>4</sub> = 00000000000000000000016***
   - ***k<sub>4</sub> = 10100010000000400041852***
7. ***f<sup>−1</sup>(10100010000000400041852)***
8. Strip off the leading ***1***: ***0100010000000400041852***
9. Take each alternating digit:

   - ***x<sub>3</sub> = 00000000015***
   - ***k<sub>3</sub> = 10100040482***
10. ***f<sup>−1</sup>(10100040482)***
11. Strip off the leading ***1***: ***0100040482***
12. Take each alternating digit:

    - ***x<sub>2</sub> = 00008***
    - ***k<sub>2</sub> = 10442***
13. ***f<sup>−1</sup>(10442)***
14. Strip off the leading ***1***: ***0442***
15. Take each alternating digit:

    - ***x<sub>1</sub> = 04***
    - ***k<sub>1</sub> = 42***
16. ***f<sup>−1</sup>(42)***
17. Strip off the leading ***1***: there is none, so we know this cannot be an output of ***f***.

It is possible that ***k<sub>1</sub>*** starts with a ***1*** and has an odd number of digits, in which case it will be falsely identified as a valid encoding. For example, if ***k<sub>1</sub> = 123***, then ***f<sup>−1</sup>(123) = (2, 3)***, so we will falsely conclude that there has been a zeroth iteration with ***x<sub>0</sub> = 2*** and ***k<sub>0</sub> = 3***. But being able to distinguish ***k<sub>n</sub>*** which are the result of an application of ***f*** from ***k<sub>1</sub>*** which are an initial input is not a requirement, so that's not a problem.

Comment: Thank you, now I know it's possible! But isn't there something that wouldn't grow at this rate in size?

Comment: I gave no thought to optimizing the size of the encoding. It should be trivial to find a better one. However, it should be obvious that the output must always be larger than the previous one, since the output must contain all the information of all previous iterations. So, no matter how clever the encoding, no matter how well you compress it, the informational complexity of the output must be at least as big as the sum of the informational complexities of the inputs, which means that the informational complexity of the output of each iteration must be at least as big as the previous one's.